# Switch Images on Button click iOS

Tags: ios, audio

I have a sound image for my app that whenever you click it, The sound turns off and the image changes. However, whenever I press it again to turn the sound back on the image just highlights and stay at the old image. Here is my code. Help would be appreciated.

```
 -(IBAction)pauseSound
{
    if (![sound isPlaying]) {
        [sound play];
        [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Sound On iOS.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }else {
        [sound pause];
        [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Sound Off iOS.png"] forState:UIControlStateReserved];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a [look at the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uicontrol_class/reference/reference.html) for the control states of a `UIControl` and for your query you can use the `UIControlStateNormal` instead of `UIControlStateReserved`.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
[button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Sound Off iOS.png"] forState:**UIControlStateNormal**];
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the off image for `UIControlStateReserved`, so when the button state returns to normal (`UIControlStateNormal`) it'll return to the previous image.

For fixing that you need to change :

```
[button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Sound Off iOS.png"] forState:UIControlStateReserved];
```

to:

```
[button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Sound Off iOS.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```